# How to close other panels when another one is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I'm newbie in bootstrap and jquery, using the code below to create many bootstrap panels, my problem is that I would like to close the others panels when i click in full size icon of one panel
someone know how can do it? 
thank you

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"> Panel Widget Title
      <div class="pull-right"> <a href="#" data-perform="panel-dismiss" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> <a href="#" data-perform="panel-collapse" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a> </div>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body"> Panel Widget Body </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"> Panel Widget Title
      <div class="pull-right"> <a href="#" data-perform="panel-dismiss" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> <a href="#" data-perform="panel-collapse" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a> </div>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body"> Panel Widget Body </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"> Panel Widget Title
      <div class="pull-right"> <a href="#" data-perform="panel-dismiss" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> <a href="#" data-perform="panel-collapse" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a> </div>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-wrapper collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body"> Panel Widget Body </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    (function($, window, document){
    var panelSelector = '[data-perform="panel-collapse"]';

    $(panelSelector).each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
    parent = $this.closest('.panel'),
    wrapper = parent.find('.panel-wrapper'),
    collapseOpts = {toggle: false};

    if( ! wrapper.length) {
    wrapper =
    parent.children('.panel-heading').nextAll()
    .wrapAll('<div/>')
    .parent()
    .addClass('panel-wrapper');
    collapseOpts = {};
    }
    wrapper
    .collapse(collapseOpts)
    .on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $this.children('i').removeClass('fa-minus').addClass('fa-plus');
    })
    .on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $this.children('i').removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');
    });
    });
    $(document).on('click', panelSelector, function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).closest('.panel');
    var wrapper = parent.find('.panel-wrapper');
    wrapper.collapse('toggle');
    });
    }(jQuery, window, document));


    (function($, window, document){
    var panelSelector = '[data-perform="panel-dismiss"]';
    $(document).on('click', panelSelector, function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parent = $(this).closest('.panel');
    removeElement();

    function removeElement() {
    var col = parent.parent();
    parent.remove();
    col.filter(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    return (el.is('[class*="col-"]') && el.children('*').length === 0);
    }).remove();
    }
    });
    }(jQuery, window, document));

    });
</script>
```

[**JSFIDDLE link**](http://jsfiddle.net/dev_java/gv5xbeve/)

Comment: What is current issue.. Like does it throw any error? if yes what is the point at which error occurs.. Any thing you have already tried??

Comment: Please add your code in fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap provides [collapse.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111511/how-to-close-other-panels-when-another-one-is-opened) to do the same.

here is the reference: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse).

or go to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragraninga/1sdgc63m/)

you just need to do this:

```
$('.panel-title a').collapse();
```

Comment: please read the question carefully before answering. user doesn't asked anything about the accordion, and his requirement is different from accordion. please read the conversation carefully

Comment: @robodev i have refered him collapse plugin because he is using collapse() function in his script in the question & he wants to close other panels when one panel header clicked. i think you have  answered the same as my answer in your previous fiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

since your question is little vague, I am not clear about your requirement. 
please have a look on to this code. I think this might be you a re asking

fiddled [here](https://jsfiddle.net/eg0zgngn/)

**HTML**

```
//Same as in you code, java script part is not needed
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".panel-heading").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".panel").find(".panel-body").toggleClass("hide");
    });
    $(".fa.fa-times").click(function(){
        $(".panel-body").addClass("hide");
        $(this).parent(".panel").find(".panel-body").removeClass("hide");
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eg0zgngn/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but isn't what i would like to do, in fact i want when i click on panel header buton i resize the current panel and i close the others ones

Comment: "panel header button" ? what is that ? and what you mean by current panel ? .

Comment: <a href="#" data-perform="panel-dismiss" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a> is the buton in each panel header, that i use now to close the current panel i mean the panel that user click on it with the mouse

Comment: What i would like to do is when i click on this buton of panel the other panels close and this current panel still opened

Comment: that means you want to open the panel when you click on the header and you want other panels to be closed when you click on the minimize icon, isn't it ?

Comment: thank you but  i want other panels to be closed when i click not just the body of the panel

Comment: @robodev Your demo is not properly: when one panel is open that time other one should be close

Comment: @VishalPatel I have done like that in previous version. since the questioner not satisfied with that, I have changed to this